# Duda sobre operador en c++

Tags: c++, imagen, operador

Estoy empezando a trabajar con imágenes bmp en c++ y hay algún operador del cual no logro comprender su funcionamiento bien, básicamente se tratan de estos: (str cadena de string)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

void ocultar(BMP & bmp, char * str){
 int pixelsRequeridos = (1 + strlen(str)) * 8; 
 if (pixelsRequeridos <= bmp.nPixels)
 {
    char * pixel;
    for (pixel = bmp.pixels; *str; str++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++, *pixel++)
        {
            char bit = ((*str) >> i) & 1; //Operador que no entiendo
            if(bit)
                *pixel |= 1;    //Operador que no entiendo
            else
                *pixel &= 0xfe; //Operador que no entiendo    
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++, *pixel++)  
        *pixel &= 0xfe;
 }
```

}

Comment: ¿Podrías copiar/pegar el código y luego, tras seleccionarlo de nuevo, pulsar en `{}` para que no rompa el formado de código? Eso será mejor que una imagen. También qué `#include`s usas y más código para saber qué tipo de dato es lo que preguntas. Gracias.

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta contexto. Añade el código alrededor de la imagen. Hablando de imágenes, no sirve de nada colgar la captura del código, una imagen no se puede compilar ni el texto que contiene se puede copiar y pegar.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, lee el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender como funciona el sitio y [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya he modificado la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char bit = ((*str) >> i) & 1;
```

Vamos a analizarlo por partes:

- `*str` -> el operador `*` sirve para desreferenciar un puntero, si tienes `char*` el operador `*` te permite acceder al `char` referenciado por el puntero.
- `X >> i` -> el operador `>>` es, en este caso, un operador binario de desplazamiento de bits. Lo que hace es desplazar hacia la derecha los bits de la variable `X`, que en tu caso es `*str`. ¿Qué es el desplazamiento de bits? Te muestro un ejemplo sencillo:

  ```
  11 >> 2 = 2 => 01011 >> 2 = 00010
  ```
- `Y & 1` -> el operador `&` realiza una operación AND nivel de bit:

  ```
  11 & 7 = 3 => 01011 & 00111 = 00011
  ```

Más cosillas:

```
if(bit)
    *pixel |= 1;    //Operador que no entiendo
else
    *pixel &= 0xfe; //Operador que no entiendo
```

Veamos:

El operador `|` es un operador OR a nivel de bit:

```
11 | 6 = 15 => 01011 | 00110 = 01111
```

Y el operador `|=` es un *alias* de lo siguiente:

```
*pixel = *pixel | 1;
```

Por otro lado, el operador `&` ya lo hemos visto antes, realiza una operación AND a nivel de bit. Y el operador `&=` hace lo mismo que el operador `|=` pero con una operación AND. Es decir, esa instrucción sería equivalente a:

```
*pixel = *pixel & 0xfe
```

Comment: +1 quizá lo que no entiende es que `a &= b` es lo mismo que `a = a & b`

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya, había hecho los cambios pero me fuí a otra pestaña y se me olvidó guardarlos... en consecuencia la respuesta estaba incompleta

Comment: Ahora te ha quedado perfecto :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo entiendo